# Logout from Gmail account without logging out Google Play Store account

Tags: google-play-store, gmail, google-account

I tried logging out the account on Gmail, but it logged out the Play Store as well. How can I logout of my Gmail account without logging out of the Google Play Store? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible according to this guide https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2991620?hl=en

> There’s no option to sign out of the Gmail app for Android without
>   removing your entire account from your phone or tablet. However, you
>   can accomplish many of the same tasks through other actions, depending
>   on what you need.

As an example you can disable Gmail sync and just check your email from the web browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean log out of the Google account, it is not possible. You will always need to be logged in to access the store for your apps. As is said before, you can disable the email service.