# Remotely view and log out of Gmail accounts used to sign in on Android phones

Tags: gmail

I have a Gmail account that I have logged in to on multiple phones. I use it only to download things from the Play Store (don't even check email from the phones). I mostly access this account from a PC browser to view emails.

How can I check which phones I am currently logged in on from this account, and how do I remotely log out of them if necessary?

The "last account activity" link at the bottom of the Gmail PC browser interface seems to only show other browsers where I have logged in to view email. I would like to see a list of phones I am currently logged in to, the history of all phones I have logged into before if this is available, and log out of them individually as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all logged-on devices connected to your Google account on the "Google Your devices" web site:
https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity

For each Android device you can select in it's three-dots-menu to logout on this device.

Note that this totally disables the device for Play Store and Gmail on the selected device. This is by design as you can not logout one specific service like GMail but keep the account active for Play Store:

[Logout from Gmail account without logging out Google Play Store account](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88528/logout-from-gmail-account-without-logging-out-google-play-store-account)

Comment: https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity: this link is what I was looking for. How would I have found it in the gmail browser interface?

Comment: @user17915 Search in Google search for `google device logout` and you will find this page. Not sure how to reach this from within GMail. As the logout functionality belongs to the account and not to Gmail my assumption is that it will require a lot of clicks to get there.